# how do i get this div to go over the other div

Tags: html, css

I got this search "asyoutype" and the result is supose to show up with all the hits, now the problem is that it wont go over the "container" div that wrapps the search and menu. I tried different positions with no success, anybody got any ideas? let me know if i need to update with more info.

this is my css for the asyoutype resultdiv

```
.searchResult
{
    background: #fff;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    width: 265px;
    z-index: 10000;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 5px #333;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 5px #333;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 5px #333;
    position: absolute; 
    right: 40px;
    top: 36px;
}
```

this is the container header (html5)

```
header.main {
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-image: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #F4F4F4, #D1D1D1) repeat scroll 0 0 #E4E4E4;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
    border-color: #C7C8C8;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 1px;
    margin: 0 0 22px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```

[image]

Comment: We might need to see more code, a jsfiddle or an example on your serever. @Sandeep: use z-index property how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that `.searchResult` lives in `header.main` in the DOM. Because `header.main` has `overflow: hidden`, `.searchResult` disappears. You should move `.searchResult` out of `header.main` in your HTML, or remove the `overflow: hidden` directive.

Comment: yea the overflow: hidden fixed it. now i just need to se if removing it causes any other problems tho. thanks

Comment: I guess it's used for clearing floated divs, there are various other ways to fix that: http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html

Comment: yes thats it, hm seems ok. great link ill have a look at that.